# Capistrano with PostgreSQL, error: database is being accessed by other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I have a Rails app that uses PostgreSQL as a backend with a cert environment that tries to mimic production, except that it needs to have the database reset periodically for QA.

When I attempt to execute `db:reset` from a Capistrano task during deployment I get the error:

`ERROR:  database "database_name" is being accessed by other users`

and the database cannot be dropped as part of the reset task resulting in deployment failing. Is there a way I can reset database connections from Capistrano so I can successfully drop the table? Piping the SQL to psql from a Capistrano task might work but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have combined [dbenhur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924466/killing-postgresql-connections-from-capistrano/12924735#12924735) with this Capistrano task to achieve the result I needed works like a charm:

```
desc 'kill pgsql users so database can be dropped'
task :kill_postgres_connections do
  run 'echo "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname=\'database_name\';" | psql -U postgres'
end
```

This assumes the auth_method for user postgres set to 'trust' in pg_hba.conf

Then you can just call it in your deploy task after `update_code` and before `migrate`

```
after 'deploy:update_code', 'kill_postgres_connections'
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need echo and pipe to send statements to psql. just use the `-c` cmdline option.

Comment: @dbenhur : can you update your comment with the -c option included ?

Answer (score 55):

With PostgreSQL you can issue the following statement to return the backend pids of all open connections other than then this one:

```
SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Then you can issue a a termination request to each of those backends with

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend($1);
```

Binding the pids returned from the first statement to each pg_terminate_backend exec.

If the other connections are not using the same user as you, you will have to connect as a superuser to successfully issue the terminates.

- [Admin signalling functions docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL)
- [Monitoring stats functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCTIONS)
- [pg_stat_activity view docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)

UPDATE: Incorporating comments and expressing as Capistrano task:

```
desc "Force disconnect of open backends and drop database"
task :force_close_and_drop_db do
  dbname = 'your_database_name'
  run "psql -U postgres",
      :data => <<-"PSQL"
         REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE #{dbname} FROM public;
         ALTER DATABASE #{dbname} CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
         SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
           FROM pg_stat_activity
           WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid()
           AND datname='#{dbname}';
         DROP DATABASE #{dbname};
      PSQL
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname FROM public;` then `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();` followed by `DROP DATABASE dbname;`. This gets rid of the race where new clients connect continually so you never get enough time to DROP the db.

Comment: Another recommendation: First, run "ALTER DATABASE dbname CONNECTION LIMIT 0;" then terminate query. Setting connection limit to 0 is not an obstacle to connect the database for you if you are using psql.

Comment: In the version that I'm using (9.1.9), pid is not a column name, but procpid is:
SELECT procpid FROM pg_stat_activity where procpid <> pg_backend_pid();

Comment: I just get `ERROR:  there is no parameter $1`.

Comment: @mkataja `$1` is a placeholder for the pid of the backend you wish to terminate.  If you're just executing sql statements with psql, literally substitute the pid number for $1.  If you're writing a program, most db interface libraries offer methods to bind parameter values to statements containing `$x` placeholders, so use that to supply an integer containing the pid to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply monkeypatch the ActiveRecord code that does the dropping.

For Rails 3.x:

```
# lib/tasks/databases.rake
def drop_database(config)
  raise 'Only for Postgres...' unless config['adapter'] == 'postgresql'
  Rake::Task['environment'].invoke
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all "select pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='#{config['database']}' AND state='idle';"
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection config.merge('database' => 'postgres', 'schema_search_path' => 'public')
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_database config['database']
end
```

For Rails 4.x:

```
# config/initializers/postgresql_database_tasks.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Tasks
    class PostgreSQLDatabaseTasks
      def drop
        establish_master_connection
        connection.select_all "select pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='#{configuration['database']}' AND state='idle';"
        connection.drop_database configuration['database']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(from: http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2014/01/10/how-to-drop-your-postgres-database-with-rails-4/)