# Rails deployment - how do you do rake db:reset with capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

I am using Linode with Ubuntu 10.04 and Capistrano, Unicorn, & Nginx to deploy.

How do I do the equivalent of `heroku run rake db:reset` with this setup? Is it as simple as `cap deploy:cold` again to run the migrations?

I've already deployed and want to drop all databases and rerun all the migrations but am not sure which commands to run with this setup to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a tiny little file you can copy to run arbitrary rake tasks via capistrano: http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/09/10/the-one-where-you-run-rake-commands-with-capistrano/

once setup, you can:

```
cap sake:invoke task="db:reset"
```

Comment: When I try to run this, I get: PGError: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

Comment: You may also need to monkey-patch the db:reset task, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047289/869616

Answer (score 4):

For Capistrano 3 without actual dropping the database. Use `bundle exec cap db:reset`

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Resets DB without create/drop'
  task :reset do
    on primary :db do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:stage) do
          execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
          execute :rake, 'db:seed'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following to your deploy.rb file

```
namespace :custom do
  task :task do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
```

Then run `cap custom:task` to clear the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Capistrano 3, consider using the [capistrano-rails-collection](https://github.com/dei79/capistrano-rails-collection).

You can also use copy the code directly from [db.rake](http://capistrano-rails-collection/lib/capistrano/tasks/db.rake) file from the repository.

Or, if you want a full-fledged solution to run all your rake tasks on a remote server, check out the [Cape](http://njonsson.github.io/cape/) gem.