# I added an hstore column in Rails and updated my seeds.db file. How do I reset and seed the database with Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to learn Capistrano (version 3) and I'm tinkering around deploying to a "test" production server.

When I run:

```
cap production deploy
```

If I want to reset and seed the database, do I create a separate task for this? Or is there something already built-in Capistrano to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Rails deployment - how do you do rake db:reset with capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926461/rails-deployment-how-do-you-do-rake-dbreset-with-capistrano)

`rake db:reset` will automatically run your seeds file